How do I refresh a "Get Rows (V2)" view of the data?
I'm building a Power Automate flow using the SQL Server connector's Get Rows (v2) to pull data from a view. The view's definition has changed, removing some columns from the view, so now the flow fails since it's trying to pull in columns that no longer exist.
How do I get the automation step to refresh so that it's no longer trying to pull in those columns and instead knows about the columns that currently exist?
The only way I see to do it at the moment is to delete the step and recreate it, but that seems... extreme, but I wouldn't put it past MS that this is the only way. I'm just hoping there's something better.
The original view definition was like:
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
FROM MyTable

The new view definition is like:
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM MyTable

So now the Get Rows is complaining:
Microsoft SQL: Invalid column name 'ColD'.

I’d suggest changing it out to execute a query instead of using get rows. I’ve never used it but it sounds like you may have your answer though. Does just changing the flow and saving it help?

I'd initially used the Execute Query, but it seems that Get Rows is the preferred method. I've "fixed" it by redoing all the column assignments (a major hassle), but I'd still like to know if there's a better way.

you  can use  this configuration

